# Spring roo and jOOQ

Tags: oracle, spring, jpa, spring-roo, jooq

jOOQ should be an alternative to standard JPA. Is there any way to use it in Roo as JPA provider? Is it even possible?

The reason for this: We have Oracle database and jOOQ has quick and easy set up for connection to that database. On the other hand, Roo is very usefull tool but lacks on setting up Oracle database connection.

Comment: Why would you think you could use it as a JPA provider ? It doesn't implement JPA, hence Roo cannot call it like any other JPA implementation.

Comment: It was just an idea from my colleague, he said jOOQ implements/is JPA so it would be possible to use it in Roo as JPA provider. It looks like he was wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jOOQ doesn't implement JPA. It just happens to support a few JPA annotations, which is far from actually implementing JPA. In other words, no you cannot use jOOQ as a JPA provider in Spring Roo